# NGX-Mask special characters

Tags: angular, regex, masking, ngx-mask

I have a functionality where I defined custom pattern and it should allow user to enter any alphabets, numbers, spaces and special characters. In this example lets say $

At the same time I have '$' as special character.

When I enter '$', app is behaving so weirdly and value in textbox is getting disturbed totally.

Below is the code for mask, specialCharacters and regex for customPatterns.

Also please check this in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-mask-formly-qwmxyz)

```
mask: string = '$(XX:XXXX)';

maskingSpecialCharacters = ['_', '-', '(', ')', '$', '.', '/'];

public customPatterns = {
// X => Retains as typed.Can take in special characters, numbers, alphabets , spaces
X: { pattern: new RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9 -$~`!@#%^&*+={}[]|:;"<>,?]') },
};
```